# pandas Timestamp object not recognizing certain attributes and methods

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, timestamp

I have a collection of very simple code that isn't working as the documentation says:

This is what the df looks like:

```
        Date                Symbol  Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   2020-03-13 08-PM    ETHUSD  129.94  131.82  126.87  128.71  1940673.93
1   2020-03-13 07-PM    ETHUSD  119.51  132.02  117.10  129.94  7579741.09
2   2020-03-13 06-PM    ETHUSD  124.47  124.85  115.50  119.51  4898735.81
3   2020-03-13 05-PM    ETHUSD  124.08  127.42  121.63  124.47  2753450.92
4   2020-03-13 04-PM    ETHUSD  124.85  129.51  120.17  124.08  4461424.71
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ETH_1h.csv')


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')
```

but `df.loc[0, 'Date'].day_name()` gives

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'day_name'
```

when the documentation states that any Timestamp object (which that iloc query is) has that attribute.

Comment: Which version of Python/pandas are you using? For me, your code works perfectly fine... (Python 3.9 / pandas 1.2.3).

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.loc[0, 'Date'].dt.day_name()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

It's the accessor object for datetimelike properties of the Series values.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['2021-01-01']])
>>> df[0]
0    2021-01-01
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
>>> df
           0
0 2021-01-01
>>> df[0].dt.day_name()
0    Friday
```

Comment: the `dt` accessor is for the attributes of the whole datetime Series - but that doesn't help if calling an attribute fails already for an individual element of the Series.